# EF4 POCO duplicate table names

Tags: entity-framework, poco

I'm currently trying to migrate a project to EF4 POCOs in order to get rid of EntityObject in my business logic and ran into an issue with duplicate table names. The DAL has access to 3 different databases and there are 3 .edmx files, one for each database.

However, some tables in those databases share the same name, e.g. DB1.CUSTOMER and DB2.CUSTOMER. I managed to have the related entities created in different namespaces (one namespace for each database) like MyApp.Db1.CUSTOMER and MyApp.Db2.CUSTOMER, the trouble is EF can't decide which one to pick and claims there was an ambiguity which isn't actually the case.

Is there any way of mapping Entities to their respective POCOs manually or any sort of workaround? This is EF 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF doesn't use namespace when recognizing entity type. The name of class is matched directly with name of entity in your model diagram (EDMX). So the workaround is using different names in different models which will also make your code much better readable.

Comment: It's as I feared then. I have no problem with renaming entities in the model. However, renaming the tables themselves is not an option as my project is not the only one accessing those DBs. So the only way is to map those tables to entities in the EDMX. I figure I can do so in the SSDL by changing the EntityType for a given EntitySet. That leaves the problem of future updates (i.e. will those changes be overwritten if I update the model from the DB).

Comment: You cannot change anything in SSDL. SSDL describes real names of tables in the database. Just rename your entities in diagram and it should automatically update mapping from table to your new entity name.